# HWadress incomplete

Tags: networking

I can not connect to internet on my new desktop with Ubuntu 16.04

```
jh@jh-System-Product-Name:~$ mii-tool
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth0' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth1' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth2' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth3' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth4' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth5' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth6' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth7' failed: Operation not permitted
no MII interfaces found
```

What does this mean?

I have checked the driver and routing table

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.129.32.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
10.129.32.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp3s0

jh@jh-System-Product-Name:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -i Net
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:8677]

jh@jh-System-Product-Name:~$ lsmod | grep r8169
r8169                  81920  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
```

Following Gilles advice

```
sudo mii-tool
[sudo] password for milenko: 
no MII interfaces found
```

This means what?I got this with ethtool

```
    sudo ethtool enp3s0
Settings for enp3s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

And  finally,ping,no I cannot connect to gateway.

```
ping 10.129.32.1
PING 10.129.32.1 (10.129.32.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.129.45.123 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.129.45.123 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Both
ip neighbour
arp -a
gave not response.

```
arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.129.32.1                      (incomplete)

What should I do now?
```

Comment: Obviously mii-tool does not know the name of your interface, but instead tries eth0 - eth7. Mii-tool has been declared obsolete in 2003, and was replaced with ethtool. Is there some reason why you suspect the interface parameters are incorrect, or why did you try mii-tool to debug the problem? Can you ping the gateway (`10.129.32.1`)?

Comment: @JohanMyréen I could not make internet connection with my modem.Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Imagine a world where users with no root powers could handle ethernet interfaces attributes. That is what happens when you try to use `mii-tool` with your login...

Comment: Assuming 10.129.45.123 is the address of the machine you are trying to reach the net from, things look ok to me. Both your host and the gateway fall under the same netmask. What does `ip neigh` or `arp -a` say? Also double check that the gateway's address is correct (10.129.32.1).

Comment: @JohanMyréen Both gave no response.

Comment: This means the host hasn't received a MAC address from the gateway. Do you have any other hosts with known ip addresses on the network you could try to ping? Do lights on the network interface blink? Please re-check the cabling and any switches you may have.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Lights blink on my desktop,I can connect router to my laptop.Why is adress incomplete?

Comment: Can you ping your laptop? If the laptop can reach the internet, please compare the network configs to see if there is any difference, e.g. are the netmasks the same and the addresses in the same range? The router should also have the same netmask. Your desktop machine is trying to communicate with the router and for that it needs the router's MAC address. To find the address is uses the ARP protocol: it sends a broadcast message "who has got this IP address" and expects the router to send a reply. Apparently the router is unable to respond, maybe because the IP address is wrong?

Comment: @JohanMyréen I have solved this,with dynamic dhcp in /etc/network/interface,works fine now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mii-tool.8.html):

> SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth?' failed: Operation not permitted
>       Most kernels restrict access to root.

You need to run `mii-tool` as root, e.g. with `sudo mii-tool`.

In general “operation not permitted” indicates a permission problem which is not related to file permissions. Often that means you need to be root.